# Why does the 60 meter band have special operating characteristics?

Tags: united-states, frequency

[image]

Why does this band have special operating characteristics and what do they mean.

Comment: not quite sure what you're referring to here – the conditions seem to be layed out in the text you display? As to why: laws.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I think the intent of the question is to find out why the rules for the 60 meter band are so different from other bands.  That's a question worthy of a proper answer.

Comment: yeah, ok, if that's the question! Ben, can you confirm that's what you mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ARRL has [a good FAQ page](http://www.arrl.org/60-meter-faq) about the 60 meter band.  The special rules in the United States for the 60 meter band aren't due to any technical limitations.  Instead, they're a compromise to allow amateur use of the band without interfering with government use.  The primary users of the band are government agencies, and they were using it long before amateurs were granted access.  As secondary users, amateurs are required to stop transmitting when asked to do so by another user, or if they detect non-amateur transmissions on the channel.  The channels were selected because they're lightly used frequencies that are least likely to cause interference with the primary users.

Comment: Also, upper sideband (USB) is used instead of the usual amateur convention of lower sideband (LSB), because government users all use USB, and it was thought best that all users of the band should be using the same sideband.

Comment: Even if we are not asked to, we should not transmit if we hear a commercial or government signal there. All the ones I've heard use digital, ALE IIRC. One was a marine station on the Gulf coast.

Comment: @MikeWaters  Thanks.  I added some clarification about that.